# How to get a value not in different table colum

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make so that my query looks for TeamCode in different table columns HomeTeam and AwayTeam and return the Team column if the AwayTeam or HomeTeam does not have 35 in either HomeTeam or AwayTeam.

This code only finds the TeamCode that does not exist in matches table and I need to make so it show only the rows where 35 does not exist.

```
SELECT  Team
FROM    club
WHERE   TeamCode NOT    IN  (SELECT DISTINCT    
HomeTeam FROM   matches);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which column you want to be different then 35, but change it to your desired column name:

```
SELECT Team
FROM club
WHERE TeamCode NOT IN  (SELECT DISTINCT HomeTeam FROM  matches 
                        WHERE ColumnName = 35);
```

Or not exists:

```
SELECT t.team
FROM club t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from Matches s
                 where (s.awayTeam = t.team 
                     or s.HomeTeam = t.Team)
                     and s.YourColumn = 35)
```